# Using Devise to implement a front-door on a website, does Rails allow concurrent sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

First, my obligatory "I'm new to rails" statement: I'm new to rails.

Sorry for the following long-winded expository stuff, but I want to make sure I'm asking my question clearly. I'm building a sample manager for a small analytical lab. So far I have built the core user stuff using devise to manage sessions (Basically so I can use all of Devise's nice helper methods throughout my app). The users don't need to be securely separated, so there is no sign in form, it just automatically signs them in for whatever action the user wishes to do.

I would like to put a front door on the website for macro-security that signs in to either the user version of the site (described above) or the admin version. I understand how to implement this using Devise, however, I am unsure as to whether Rails allows this sort of double-session where there's a macro-security session on constantly while a bunch of internal sessions are created and destroyed. Again, sorry for the long-windedness and thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is HTTP Authentication: http://ewout.name/2010/04/http-basic-authentication-with-devise/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just give it a shot and it turns out it worked. I have to test to see if there are any kinks in the functionality, but as it stands it works well as a front-door while allowing the internal transient sessions.